# How should I answer this interview question about handling large backlogs?

Tags: interviewing

At interviews for QA positions, I have been asked the following:

> You are put into a new team that has a very large backlog of bugs raised since the project's inception. The bugs have not been reported in a good state and are mostly reported in very small one line details.
>
> Please explain what your approach to handling this would be and how you would arrange these issues into something more usable for the QA Manager to review.

My responses don't seem to be working. How should I approach answering this question?

Comment: Is this question hypothetical, or based on an actual situation you are experiencing? Please provide more context.

Comment: Do the issues record who reported them? Can you go back to that person for more information?

Comment: These questions are asked in the  QA interview. would like to know your idea and opinions because my ideas are not working out sometimes.

Comment: I've submitted an edit to clarify that you're asking us how to answer that question in an interview situation, and not actually asking us the question.

Comment: Maybe detail your responses and we can outline why they "may not be working" whatever that means.

Comment: Actually someone answered for this question on this group yesterday. But now that post was deleted and i am not able to find it. I just read and forgot to save. So that is the reason i posted it again. Could you please someone help to undelete that post. instead of wasting time here.

Comment: Sounds like a classic case of "Triage".

Comment: So how did you answer any of these questions? Or are you just predicting questions in prep for an interview? See https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/177514/75821

Comment: And this: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/48890

Answer (score 7):

QA has one single job: Assure that the products released to customers are of good enough quality. External bug reports from customers *may* help you achieving this, but often they don't.

So these bug reports are not a task that needs to be done - some of them may be a resource that can help you doing your job, some are not. In fact, most are not. If they have been collected since the project's inception, then many of them are either fixed, or in features that don't exist anymore. Your job, if your manager wants this, is to find bug reports that have value to your company because they help to improve the product.

You can agree with the QA manager that any bugreport older than X days is probably worthless by now. Then you go through the other ones, one by one. Take one. Read it. Decide whether you can tell a developer about a problem based on this. If not, you close it. Then try whether the problem still exists. If you cannot reproduce the problem, that's it. If you can reproduce the problem, you write down an actual bug report that can be given to a developer, in the most time saving way.

Repeat until the backlog is gone, or until you retire.

Comment: What in the original question indicates that these are customer reported bugs, rather than internally reported bugs?

Comment: Why does it matter?

Answer (score 3):

There are a bunch of options for how to handle this situation.  In no particular order, steps may include:

1. Close them all, without any review.  Particularly appropriate if the project is about to enter end-of-life.
2. Triage them.  "Reproducible", "Might be reproducible", and "not enough information to reproduce".
3. Triage them.  "Critical", "High", "Medium", "Low".
4. Close/link duplicates.
5. Of the "might be reproducible", try to reproduce.  If reproducible, update the report.  If not reproducible, close the report.
6. Reach out to the original reporter and request additional information.  If they cannot provide sufficient information to reproduce/triage, then close.
7. Ensure the findings are in some sort of bug tracking database (bugzilla, jira, github issues, whatever)
8. Create reports that will help management understand what work exists and what is remaining.  Valid (and given to dev) vs invalid, trends over time, bugs by severity, etc
9. Define standards for creating bugs, if such standards do not already exist.  Standard can include things like "bug is reproducible, following exact steps as written" or "report contains automated test case"
10. Define bug intake process, in which all new bugs are triaged against the standard.
11. Train all staff who open bugs how to follow the standard

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to know where you’re at… in this case, the system’s current situation and you need a clear picture of it.
If there’s no good documentation/reports of  the system and the identified bugs, that’s the first thing one should acquire.

From these bugs/issues, can you identify bigger underlying problems, such as bad decisions during the design stage of the system?
Eg. 2 issues appear  to have the same root cause, and by tackling the underlying problem, you would end up solving the two issues or make it easier to fixing it and prevent similar problems in the future.

Then, prioritise by severity, and take certain other factors into consideration - how much resources do you need to fix an issue/bug?